# Does Ubuntu works on 2012 Sony Viao S 15-inch ?

Tags: installation, sony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which version and derivate of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minmal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

Can anyone report whether Ubuntu works on the new (June 2012) Sony Viao S 15?  If so, which version?

Comment: Cannot find the Viao S 15 model. Link please.

Comment: I guess it is [this](http://www.trustedreviews.com/sony-vaio-s-15-2012_Laptop_review)

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Here's a [link to it on the Sony website](http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&categoryId=8198552921644768015).  Note that it has (optional) hybrid graphics with NVidia instead of ATI, like the previous version had.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2012 Sony Vaio S 1511C5E (Core i7-3612QM, 12GB RAM, with WWAN module, a GOBI 3000, the Intel 4000/nVidia GT640M Optimus hybrid graphics).

I run Ubuntu 12.04 on it without any major problems. I've installed Bumblebee but at the moment it causes the machine to shutdown hard if I try to run an application on the nVidia GPU (known bug the Bumblebee folks seems to be working on). Have not tested fingerprint reader, HDMI port, or suspend/hibernate.

I'm happy with the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's best to let the computer tell you. Boot up the computer on the disc, without installation. Though response time will be slow, you should get a good idea of what works and what doesn't.